# Wordpress: replacing the_content completely

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, feed

I have a collection of News Posts and I have added a guid (sha1 of the post ID) and I wanted to include the tags in the feed (make it easier to display on a webpage).

However when I update the 'description' tag, it just adds it to the response, rather than removing it so I end up with the following after a json_encode:

```
"description": [
    "header subheader the original text with no tags",    // want to remove if possible.
    {
       "h1": "header",
       "h3": "subheader",
       "p": [
           "the original text",
           "with no tags",
       ]
    }
```

]

Here is my code:

```
add_action('rss2_item', function(){
  global $post;

  $output = '';
  $output .= '<id>' . sha1($post->ID) . '</id>';
  $output .= '<description>' . wpautop( $post->post_content ) . '</description>';

  echo $output;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The action `rss2_item` just lets you add nodes to the existing feed item, you cannot remove nodes:

> The rss2_item action hook is triggered immediately after the default output of an rss2 feed.

What you need is probably a custom feed template, which can be achieved with the hook `do_feed_rss2`. From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds):

```
function my_custom_rss() {

    if ( 'photos' === get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'photos' );
    } 
    else {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'rss2' );
    }
}
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'my_custom_rss', 10, 1 );
```